# How to get Google Home assistant to read a value from the Internet?

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-home, google-assistant, ifttt

Using IFTTT, I am able to send POST REST requests, which then it is able to flip the lights on/off on my Raspberry Pi.

I can make a GET REST request (using postman) to get the value of the light, but I can't seem to figure out how to get google home/assistant to read that value for me.

Value returned from the GET REST request:

```
{
    "id": "sw1",
    "state": "off",
    "name": "Pi light"
}
```

This is the flow:

Question:

> "Hey Google, is the light on or off?"

Google assistant answer:

> "The light is turned on" or "The light is turned off"

I have searched everywhere, tried a couple things using IFTTT webhooks, but I just don't seem to be able to connect the dots.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: How do you imagine this working? What have you done to link Google Assistant to the Pi? Is it through IFTTT? Can Google Assistant do other IFTTT actions?

Comment: You can add Google assistant on IFTTT (then-Field) on the IFTTT android app so it automatically fetch data from internet and triggers assistant accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it can be done by switching to Alexa  ;-)

I'm in a similar fix: I have a weather station that can report current conditions with a JSON message in response to an HTTP request. I was able to write an Alexa skill that could fetch the message and compose a spoken response.

I picked up a Home Mini during the Christmas sale because I've read it does better at things like web searches, and am trying to do something similar with it.

As far as I can tell, that can't be done with IFTTT: you can send commands, but there's no "then that" service that will query and speak a response.

It *looks like* it can be done with Google Actions, but I can't be certain yet: I've had a hard time finding simple examples or tutorials to learn and/or crib from. It's annoying when makers name their products with common words like "home" or "actions": it's a request to the gods to make finding info about them as difficult as possible.

Look into the "Actions SDK" on Google Actions. Avoid Dialogflow: it's for making really complex interactions, and will make an attempt at a simple one complicated. Not that the SDK is all that simple, but it looks like the only option at the moment.